# Include javascript modules inside a html file. (Vanilla javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, module

I have a multi file webpage, but I just want one file (index.html). because this seems the easiest way to display it using android webview. I have a javascript file a javascript module and the html file.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <script type="module">import * as Module from './Module.js';</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I know how to include normal scripts in the webpage, but how do I embed the module Module.js in index.html.

I want to do something like this...

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <script type="module" src="Module.js">
        export function CallHello(){
            console.log("Hello");
        }
    </script>
    <script type="module">
        import * as Module from './Module.js';
        Module.CallHello();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: "how do I embed the module Module.js in index.html" -- it looks like you just did. What's the problem with this code? What do you mean by "embed" exactly?

Comment: I have 3 files. index.html, Paint.js, and UIManager.js. I just want one file 'index.html'. Paint.js imports UIManager.js. But I don't know how to include UIManager inside the index.html file.

Comment: The syntax you posted seems fine. How is it not working? That said, if you're not doing anything with the `Module` object, just `<script type="module" src="./Module.js"></script>` should work.